# Для чего используется выходной параметр OUT в хранимых процедурах mysql?

Tags: mysql

Пример использования входного параметра:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`(
    IN country_id int
)
BEGIN
    select * from country where id = country_id;
END;|

\d ;
```

Для получения результата я должен вызвать хранимую процедуру с входным параметром:

```
call new_procedure(3);
```

Для чего же тогда используется OUT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробую объяснить простым языком. В случаях, когда у вас в результате выполнения процедуры необходимо вернуть единичные значения удобнее использовать выходные параметры, а не набор данных. Это упрощает манипулирование выходными данными за пределами процедуры.

Пример процедуры с выводом набора данных:

```
DELIMITER \\

CREATE PROCEDURE p_dataset (IN id INT)
BEGIN
   IF id >= 10 THEN INSERT SELECT 1 as res;
   ELSE SELECT 0 as res;
   END IF;
END\\

DELIMITER ;

CALL p_dataset (11);

DROP PROCEDURE p_dataset;
```

В данном случае вы всегда получите набор данных с одной строкой. Для дальнейшего манипулирования полученным значением, необходимо совершить дополнительные действия с выводимым процедурой набором данных.

Вариант с выходным параметром, напротив, дает вам на выходе конкретную переменную (или переменные), которую дальше можно сразу использовать вне процедуры:

```
DELIMITER \\

CREATE PROCEDURE p_out (IN id INT, OUT result INT)
BEGIN
    IF id >= 10 THEN SET result = 1;
    ELSE SET result = 0;
    END IF;
END\\

DELIMITER ;

CALL p_out (1, @res_out);

SELECT @res_out;

DROP PROCEDURE p_out;
```

Answer (score 0):

Цитата из [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) :

```
mysql> delimiter //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT)
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM t;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;

mysql> CALL simpleproc(@a);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @a;
+------+
| @a   |
+------+
| 3    |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Какие значения может принимать выходной параметр(каким типом данных может быть out?). Вы можете привести реальные примеры его использования?

Comment: *каким типом данных может быть out?* - любой скалярный, поддерживаемый MySQL. *Вы можете привести реальные примеры его использования?* - приведённый в мануале пример - реальный.